# How do I apply a macro to all selected text?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, microsoft-word-2016

A former co-worker created a wraptext macro for us when processing documents for import into another program.

I was finally able to find the code he created for us.
Right now it only works for each section in a Word doc individually.

```
Sub WrapText()

' WrapText Macro
Dim p As Variant
Dim i As Long

On Error Resume Next
'count the number of paragraphs
    p = Selection.Paragraphs.Count

'Position the cursor at the end of the first paragraph. MoveDown is used
'because it works with the wdParagraph unit.  Other commands only work with
'lines or sentences.
    Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseStart)
    Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
    Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

'Begin loop.  p -1 prevents wrapping text from the paragraph following the selection
    For i = 1 To p - 1
        Selection.TypeText Text:=" ## "
        Selection.Delete unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
        Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EXAMPLE DOCUMENT TEXT**

This is what the document would look like with Headings and Body Text.(I also included the hard return points we are trying to replace)

```
1. SCOPE^p
    Summarizing, then, we assume that most of the 
    methodological work in modern linguistics is not quite 
    equivalent to the traditional practice of grammarians.^p

    Of course, the earlier discussion of deviance suffices to 
    account for nondistinctness in the sense of distinctive 
    feature theory.^p

    1.1 Heading2^p
        Summarizing, then, we assume that most of the 
        methodological work in modern linguistics is not quite 
        equivalent to the traditional practice of grammarians.^p

        Of course, the earlier discussion of deviance suffices to 
        account for nondistinctness in the sense of distinctive 
        feature theory.^p
```

Now running the macro would make the above text look like this.

```
Running the macro the first time with the text selected below
1. SCOPE^p
    Summarizing, then, we assume that most of the 
    methodological work in modern linguistics is not quite 
    equivalent to the traditional practice of grammarians.##Of 
    course, the earlier discussion of deviance suffices to 
    account for nondistinctness in the sense of distinctive 
    feature theory.##

Running the macro a second time with the text selected below
    1.1 Heading2^p
        Summarizing, then, we assume that most of the 
        methodological work in modern linguistics is not quite 
        equivalent to the traditional practice of grammarians.##Of 
        course, the earlier discussion of deviance suffices to 
        account for nondistinctness in the sense of distinctive 
        feature theory.##
```

Right now I would have to run this macro on each individual section manually and it would replace any hard returns it finds with ## (We use the ## in another program to process the data after import).

I tried to do workarounds by doing a replace all ^p with Style: Body Text selected but it still replaces the paragraph markings in a word doc for everything except for Heading 1 style.

I wanted to know if there was a way possible to have this code run over all selected text in the Word Doc or possibly running over all text in a Word doc except for Headings/Captions/Tables

Or if there is an easier way of doing this that I am not aware of.

Comment: any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking if following paragraph has same Body Text style - if it does not then skip replacement:

```
Sub WrapText()
Dim para as Paragraph
For Each para in ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
   para.Range.Select
   'if this is last para, no need to check
   If ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.End).Paragraphs.Count = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count Then Exit For
   If para.Style="Body Text" then
      If para.Next.Style="Body Text" then para.Range = Replace(para.Range, Chr(13), "##")
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: When i try to run this I am getting a compile error: Syntax Error.

Comment: Sorry in my hurry to copy type, I missed the closing quotation mark after the ## (before the closing bracket) - code updated.  Hopefully that's all that needs fixing.

Comment: Works great thank you!

The only question I have is there a reason why para.style = "Body Text" is set but yet I keep noticing that this is still affecting Section Headings?

I even went so far as to select all headings and make sure they are set to Heading 1, 2, 3 etc but yet this is still modifying Section headings when I run it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't replicate the error at all - it should only do something if the style is Body Text.  I run it on Word 2010.